# Peach root fungus?

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases, peaches

Could someone recognize the disease in these peach tree roots? The smell is hard to describe but it's definitely not pleasing.

[image: root fungus]

Comment: How are the trees themselves doing? If they are doing fine this could just be hyphae, which is a beneficial white fungi that many plants develop.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention it, but I removed the tree after a couple weeks from showing the first signs of death.

Comment: Shriveled fruit and yellowing leaves followed by defoliation and eventually stem dieback?

Comment: @Rob EXACTLY! Except that the tree was still very small and had no fruits when it started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that you have yourself a case of white root rot disease or maybe Armillaria root rot. Armillaria has a funky smell something like mushrooms. Either way, there is no cure and the treatment is to quarantine and destroy the effect entity. After you have disposed of the infected plant be sure to disinfect all your tools and any containers you plan to reuse with alcohol in order to prevent the spread of the disease.